# multiple readStreams pipe to request

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest, http-request

Is it possible to send off multiple images to a remote server in one go or do I've to make separate requests?

```
var http = require('http');
var request = http.request(options, function(response) {

}

var readStream = fs.ReadStream(images[0]);
readStream.on('error', reject);
readStream.on('close', function(){request.end()});
readStream.pipe(request);
```

Comment: It is fs.ReadStream or fs.createReadStream ?

Comment: I think both are same, https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream